# Should I report Employer Tuition Assistance? (what if it's paid after tax year?)

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, education, tuition

*I live, work and attend school in the U.S.*

My employer has a tuition assistance program in place that covers 100% of tuition and eligible expenses up to $5000 **per calendar year**. My plan was to attend 3 half-year terms of college and get reimbursed over 3 calendar years.

I attended college the latter half of 2019 accruing $3755 in tuition with another $500 scholarship applied. Thus, I received a total reimbursement of $3255 from my employer and was paid out in 2019. I will be attending school throughout 2020 and will be paid out roughly the same amount in 2020 (July) and 2021 (January). Essentially I'll have free college which is a nice benefit, but what are the tax implications here?

I am wondering:

- Is the Employer Tuition Assistance considered **financial aid**?
- Do I need to report any/all of the $3255 in Employer Tuition
  Assistance? (up to $5,250 received is considered tax-free)
- If so, do I report the Employer Tuition Assistance as "Grants and Scholarships"?
- Should I include my grants and scholarships in income?
- For the 2020 tax year, in which I have 2 terms of tuition but receive some Employer Tuition Assistance paid out in 2021, does this get reported in 2020 or the following tax year?
- If reported in 2021, how do I report this without having had any 1098-T for the year (or will I receive a 1098-T since the school will be paid in 2021)?

Answer (score 1):

Good news is that it is tax free. In fact you could get $5250 each year. Generally employer benefits count for the year you receive them.

> If you receive educational assistance benefits from your employer under an educational assistance program, you can exclude up to $5,250 of those benefits each year. This means your employer should not include the benefits with your wages, tips, and other compensation shown in box 1 of your Form W-2.

As for other scholarships, they are also tax free if used for qualified expenses. (Room and board don’t count for example).

> A scholarship or fellowship is tax free only if you meet the following conditions:
>
> You are a candidate for a degree at an eligible educational institution.
> You use the scholarship or fellowship to pay qualified education expenses.

Like everything, there are qualifications and criteria.

Source: https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/tax-benefits-for-education-information-center